# how to avoid multiple objects from being created in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have an issue where the value of a dropdown field is not getting persisted when saved and reopened. It has a default value of 1 month. when I change it to 4 months, save it and reopen the page, the value gets set to 1 month. I made a fix with the following code. But now I am able to see the new value of 4 months, but there is another window that is opening up. Please tell me why. Here's my code.

```
listeners: {
                afterrender: function(grid) {
                    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(0);
                    var newPullWindow = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#pullWindowItem')[0];
                    if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
                        var newPullWindowValue = record.get(newPullWindow.dataIndex);
                        newPullWindow.setValue(newPullWindowValue);
                     }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you try suspending the "pullWindowItem" component events before setting the value and again resume them.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? There is nothing in the above code that opens/creates the window(s). Also, it is not clear if the combo you mention is configured as column editor or not, neither I have a clue what means "save it and re-open the page".